# perf record: can I specify multiple events and use different sample-after value for each of them

Tags: linux-kernel, profiling, perf

I'm trying use perf tool from the linux kernel package to measure several raw PMU events. In the manpage of perf-record there is an "-l" option (Scale counter values), which is useful for my case because I want to know the total counter value, not just sample count. However it seems the -l is not recognized, is this expected? How can I get a total count?

Another question is that how can I specify multiple events and use different sample-after value for each of them? like perf record -c 10000,2000000,2000000 -e r2d4,r03c,r0c0

thank you

Answer (score 2):

in the example, I am showing I have already installed `libpfm4` so that perf knows the user-friendly event names. There is a rather clumsy default syntax that can be used that allows the sampling period to be set per event

```
levinth@ubuntu18-2:~$ perf record -e cpu/inst_retired.any_p,period=2000000/,cpu/cpu_clk_unhalted.thread_any,period=3000000/ -- sleep 5
[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.017 MB perf.data ]
```